# How can I give a name to the constant size of an array which is a member of a struct?

Tags: rust

I want to write something like this

```rust
struct Foo<T> {
  const BAR_LEN: usize = 3,
  bar: [usize; BAR_LEN],
  t: T,
}

impl<T> Foo<T> {
  fn new(t: T) -> Self {
    Self { bar: [27; Self::BAR_LEN], t }
  }
}
```

but the compiler (1.70.0 nightly) won't let me declare a constant like that inside of the struct definition. is there a correct way to do this? I'd like to avoid

- inlining the magic constant 3 everywhere
- declaring BAR_LEN outside of the scope of Foo. I want to have multiple structs with their own BAR_LENs, and I don't want them to collide in the global/module namespace.

Comment: [This example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/associated-items.html#associated-constants) says you can put it in the `impl` block and itʼll still be seen.  (Comment not answer because I havenʼt tried it and there might be some subtlety Iʼm missing)

Answer (score 3):

You can't declare constant in a struct but you can in its implementation:

```rust
struct Foo {
    bar: [usize; Self::BAR_LEN],
}

impl Foo {
    const BAR_LEN: usize = 3;

    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            bar: [27; Self::BAR_LEN],
        }
    }
}
```

See [associate constants](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/associated-items.html#associated-constants).

---

However, since you want absolutely a generic there is a problem:

```
error: generic parameters may not be used in const operations
 --> src/lib.rs:2:24
  |
2 |     bar: [usize; Foo::<T>::BAR_LEN],
  |                        ^ cannot perform const operation using `T`
  |
  = note: type parameters may not be used in const expressions

warning: cannot use constants which depend on generic parameters in types
  --> src/lib.rs:11:23
   |
11 |             bar: [27; Self::BAR_LEN],
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = warning: this was previously accepted by the compiler but is being phased out; it will become a hard error in a future release!
   = note: for more information, see issue #76200 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/76200>
   = note: `#[warn(const_evaluatable_unchecked)]` on by default
```

Rust explicitly forbidden to use a generic in constant context see [#76200](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/76200). You must use a dummy type:

```rust
struct Foo<T> {
    bar: [usize; Foo::<()>::BAR_LEN],
    t: T,
}

impl<T> Foo<T> {
    const BAR_LEN: usize = 3;
    
    fn new(t: T) -> Self {
        Self {
            bar: [27; Foo::<()>::BAR_LEN],
            t,
        }
    }
}
```

---

You can declare a const outside your impl scope, let's say you are in a mod `foo`:

```rust
mod foo {
    struct Foo<T> {
        bar: [usize; crate::foo::BAR_LEN],
        t: T,
    }

    const BAR_LEN: usize = 3;

    impl<T> Foo<T> {
        fn new(t: T) -> Self {
            Self {
                bar: [27; BAR_LEN],
                t,
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here you can access the constant by using the name directly inside module `foo` or using the absolute path `crate::foo::BAR_LEN`.

Comment: this seems to not work if there is any generic parameter (see playground link https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f548f34a7156fdae8ca7ee69a5dd536d and https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d1e062e9d5afd31d3d1fc8a598ba6ec1) - I notice that you edited this apparently-essential complexity out of my original question, can you undo that?

Answer (score -1):

Something that may help you are [const generics](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/generics.html#const-generics) with a default.

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;

struct Foo<N, const BAR_LEN: usize = 3> {
    bar: [i32; BAR_LEN],
    phantom: PhantomData<N>, // or however you're using the generic
}

impl<N, const BAR_LEN: usize> Foo<N, BAR_LEN> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            bar: [27; BAR_LEN],
            phantom: PhantomData,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let val: Foo<usize> = Foo::new();
}
```

This gives you the additional ability to create the same struct of different sizes:

```
let val: Foo<usize, 4> = Foo::new();
type Foo4<T> = Foo<T, 4>;
```

Comment: This is not what requested, this doesn't declare a constant but let the caller choose.

Comment: I disagree. This gives OP a constant they can use to define the size of an array, they don't have to hardcode the magic number (and the default value let's the actual const generic be elided usually), and BAR_LEN is local to Foo, which are all of their criteria. They never specified that it has to be hardcode to a specific value that can't be changed. In fact, while they didn't give much detail on it, they specified that they DO want to define multiple structs, with different BAR_LEN that don't collide, and this does exactly that. So this is very much what was requested